# Problems with debounce in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, debouncing

I have a form with username input and I am trying to verify if the username is in use or not in a debounce function. The issue I'm having is that my debounce doesn't seem to be working as when I type "user" my console looks like

```
u
us
use
user
```

Here is my debounce function

```
export function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;

    return () => {
        var context = this, args = arguments;

        var later = () => {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };

        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

And here is how I'm calling it in my React component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react' 

// verify username
useEffect(() => {
    if(state.username !== "") {
        verify();
    }
}, [state.username])

const verify = debounce(() => {
    console.log(state.username)
}, 1000);
```

The debounce function seems to be correct? Is there a problem with how I am calling it in react?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Every time your component re-renders, a **new** debounced `verify` function is created, which means that inside `useEffect` you are actually calling different functions which defeats the purpose of debouncing.

It's like you were doing something like this:

```
const debounced1 = debounce(() => { console.log(state.username) }, 1000);
debounced1();

const debounced2 = debounce(() => { console.log(state.username) }, 1000);
debounced2();

const debounced3 = debounce(() => { console.log(state.username) }, 1000);
debounced3();
```

as opposed to what you really want:

```
const debounced = debounce(() => { console.log(state.username) }, 1000);
debounced();
debounced();
debounced();
```

One way to solve this is to use `useCallback` which will always return the same callback (when you pass in an empty array as a second argument). Also, I would pass the `username` to this function instead of accessing the state inside (otherwise you will be accessing a stale state):

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
const App => () {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (username !== "") {
      verify(username);
    }
  }, [username]);

  const verify = useCallback(
    debounce(name => {
      console.log(name);
    }, 200),
    []
  );

  return <input onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />;
}
```

Also you need to slightly update your debounce function since it's not passing arguments correctly to the debounced function.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return (...args) => { <--- needs to use this `args` instead of the ones belonging to the enclosing scope
    var context = this;
...
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-bush-bh006?file=/src/App.js:484-829)

Note: You will see an ESLint warning about how `useCallback` expects an inline function, you can get around this by using `useMemo` knowing that `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`:

```
const verify = useMemo(
  () => debounce(name => {
    console.log(name);
  }, 200),
  []
);
```

Answer (score 20):

```
export function useLazyEffect(effect: EffectCallback, deps: DependencyList = [], wait = 300) {
  const cleanUp = useRef<void | (() => void)>();
  const effectRef = useRef<EffectCallback>();
  const updatedEffect = useCallback(effect, deps);
  effectRef.current = updatedEffect;
  const lazyEffect = useCallback(
    _.debounce(() => {
      cleanUp.current = effectRef.current?.();
    }, wait),
    [],
  );
  useEffect(lazyEffect, deps);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      cleanUp.current instanceof Function ? cleanUp.current() : undefined;
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Nice generic version! This answer deserves more upvotes. Maybe add an example on how to use it (even though it may seem obvious). And maybe add some explanatory notes.

Comment: Heres that function wrapped in a nice gist with imports and ready to use :) https://gist.github.com/felipecsl/afb987f8b6059814cff0a2ca6020e108

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better, and it's up to the reader to decide whether it's "better".

Answer (score 17):

I suggest a few changes.

1) Every time you make a state change, you trigger a render. Every render has its own props and effects. So your `useEffect` is generating a new debounce function every time you update username. This is a good case for [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hooks to keep the function instance the same between renders, or possibly [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) maybe - I stick with useCallback myself.

2) I would separate out individual handlers instead of using `useEffect` to trigger your debounce - you end up with having a long list of dependencies as your component grows and it's not the best place for this.

3) Your debounce function doesn't deal with params. (I replaced with lodash.debouce, but you can debug your implementation)

4) I think you still want to update the state on keypress, but only run your denounced function every x secs

Example:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  const verify = useCallback(
    debounce(username => {
      console.log(`processing ${username}`);
    }, 1000),
    []
  );

  const handleUsernameChange = event => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
    verify(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Debounce</h1>
      <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleUsernameChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-christian-3t9xc?file=/src/App.js:0-600)

I highly recommend reading this great [post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) on useEffect and hooks.

Comment: Would you suggest breaking up [state, setState] = { step: 1, name: "", email: "", username: "", password: "", confirm: "", error: "", verified: "", valid: false } into individual useStates? I understand why doing so for handling the username and the debounce.

Comment: Yes, I would separate the state and relevant handlers so you have `[username, setUsername] handleUsernameChange()` `[password, setPassword] handlePasswordChange()` etc

Answer (score 0):

A simple `debounce` functionality with `useEffect`,`useState` hooks

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function DebounceInput(props) {
    const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        };
    }, [timeoutId]);

    function inputHandler(...args) {
        setTimeoutId(
            setTimeout(() => {
                getInputText(...args);
            }, 250)
        );
    }

    function getInputText(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value || "Hello World!!!");
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" onKeyDown={inputHandler} />
        </>
    );
}
```

I hope this works well. And below I attached vanilla js code for `debounce`

```
function debounce(cb, delay) {
    let timerId;
    return (...args) => {
        if (timerId) clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            cb(...args);
        }, delay);
    };
}

function getInputText(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown',debounce(getInputText,500));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a custom hook in plain JavaScript that will achieve a debounced `useEffect`:

```js
export const useDebounce = (func, timeout=100) => {
    let timer;
    let deferred = () => {
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(func, timeout);
    };
    const ref = useRef(deferred);
    return ref.current;
};

export const useDebouncedEffect = (func, deps=[], timeout=100) => {
    useEffect(useDebounce(func, timeout), deps);
}
```

For your example, you could use it like this:

```js
useDebouncedEffect(() => {
    if(state.username !== "") {
        console.log(state.username);
    }
}, [state.username])
```