# How to pass in a dynamic parameter to a function inside of a addEventListener scroll as it seems to get memoized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have states as this:

```
const [pointer, setPointer] = useState("");
```

And I update this state whenever I fetch data from an API as such:

```
const fetchData = (fileType) => {
  if (pointer === null) return;
  API.call(pointer).then((res) => setPointer(res));  
};

const triggerRefetch = () => {
  if (!hasMore) return;
  const element = loadingRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (element?.top < window.innerHeight && element.bottom >= 0) {
    fetchData(fileType);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  triggerRefetch();
  const el = document.getElementById("room-detail-container");
  el?.addEventListener("scroll", triggerRefetch);

  return () => el?.removeEventListener("scroll", triggerRefetch);
}, []);
```

So my idea is to implement some sort of an infinite scrolling feature, where if the `Loader` component is visible on the screen, it will trigger a refetch to the API. That's why I use the `addEventListener("scroll", ...)`. And I'm using this pointer to know exactly what's the next data I want to fetch. However, whenever this `triggerRefetch`, it seems that the `fetchData` function somewhat memoize the `pointer` state, so even though the `pointer` state has been updated through `setPointer(res)`, if I `console.log(pointer)` inside of the function, it returns me an empty string. Is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: setPointer doesn't update pointer until the next render.

Comment: @James I'm still a little confused, because if I try to log `pointer` outside of the function, it does get updated. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Comment: you likely want another use effect to check the scroll position and pointer have changed before making the new request. might also want to wait until scroll end before making the request, multiple scroll events will likely fire off before the api returns anything from the first request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it this way:

- `fetchData` only knows about the variables in it's surrounding scope for where it is declared. That means that on the initial render, it can see the original value of `pointer`
- `triggerRefetch` only knows about the variables in it's surrounding scope for where it is declared. That means that on the initial render, it can see the original `fetchData` function (which was created on the initial render, which again, can see the original `pointer` state)
- Your `useEffect()` only triggers once on the initial render, so `addEventListener()` is only called once and is passed the original `triggerRefetch` function created on the initial render, which in turn knows about the original `fetchData` function, which knows about the original `pointer`).

`fetchData` and `triggerRefetch` are created again on each rerender of your component, so they can then access the new version of the `pointer` state, however, since your `useEffect` triggers once on mount and only adds the event listener once with the original `triggerRefetch`, the new versions of those functions which see the latest state are never invoked.

To help resolve this, you can re-add your event listener each time `triggerRefetch` changes by updating your `useEffect` dependencies. That would normally be on every rerender (as it recreates a *new* function object), but with the help of `useCallback()` you can memoize it so that it only gets recreated when `fetchData` changes. Similarly, you can limit `fetchData` to only be recreated when the `pointer` state changes:

```js
const fetchData = useCallback((fileType) => {
  if (pointer === null) return;
  API.call(pointer).then((res) => setPointer(res));  
}, [pointer]);

const triggerRefetch = useCallback(() => {
  if (!hasMore) return;
  const element = loadingRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (element?.top < window.innerHeight && element.bottom >= 0) {
    fetchData(fileType);
  }
}, [fetchData /*, hasMore <--- depends on what hasMore is */]);

useEffect(() => {
  triggerRefetch();
  const el = document.getElementById("room-detail-container");
  el?.addEventListener("scroll", triggerRefetch);

  return () => el?.removeEventListener("scroll", triggerRefetch);
}, [triggerRefetch]);
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to solve the issue, it's just that I want to add a `debounce` function to the scroll event listener: `el?.addEventListener("scroll", debounce(() => triggerRefetch, 500));` but if I scroll maybe 20 units, then the debounce will get triggered 20 times as well. I'm guessing this is because of `triggerRefetch` being a dependency?

Comment: Hey, it may be, although `triggerRefetch` should only cause your useEffect to remount  when `pointer` changes, unless `triggerRefetch` includes other dependencies other than `fetchData`. What does your `debounce` function look like?

Comment: I'm using lodash debounce and nope, its only dependency is `fetchData`

Comment: @Owenn perhaps you can try creating a custom debounce hook (eg: https://jsfiddle.net/hsvn4cra/, note, I haven't tested this). Alternatively, you can try memoizing the debounce function that you get back to avoid it changing on the change of the useEffect (example: [Problems with debounce in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61786423)). But I'm just guessing what the issue is though, it might be easier if you can create a reproducible example using a codesanbox or something like that which will help.